# Extract 'is a company' from ABPersonRecord

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, abaddressbook

My iOS app is showing the contents of a user's address book with some app-specific UI elements. One challenge that I'm unable to figure out, is where in the [`AddressBook` framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/AddressBook_iPhoneOS_Framework/_index.html) it's stored whether a person is marked 'as a company', or not. Here's a screenshot of the checkbox in the Mac address book app (sorry for the Dutch in there, 'Bedrijf' means 'Company').

[image: Screenshot of the OSX Address Book app, 'Bedrijf' means 'Company']
[image: Screenshot of the OSX Address Book app, company checkbox is off]

You can't edit this property on an iOS device, but it syncs over if you use iCloud or some other sync service. As you see, it influences whether the first-name/last-name or the company name should be used to display this contact and it changes the placeholder icon.

I'm iterating over the contents of `ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeople(addressBook);` and extract the info I need from the `ABRecordRef` instances. I'm using the 'Personal Information Properties' constants [listed in the reference guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW8), but I just can't find the constant to get at the flag whether a person is marked as a company or a person.

I'm looking for a flag with something of 'company' or 'organization' in there, but I'm obviously looking in the wrong place. Who can point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've almost found it: [Person Type Property](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AddressBook/Reference/ABPersonRef_iPhoneOS/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007210-CH991-SW8)
`kABPersonKindProperty` property has values of `kABPersonKindPerson` or `kABPersonKindOrganization`